# SSRS slow(3min) after rendering

Tags: reporting-services

I've created a report. It takes 9335ms to query(checked by sql trace & ssrs log),  time Processing = 1513ms(ssrs log), time rendering = 35648ms(ssrs log).
With Byte count = 21470728 and row count = 12418.
Here is weird thing, according ssrs log, this report should show up around 1 min. But it doesn't. It's showing loading until 4 mins. Then report show up. I checked with Chrome/IE dev tool, the report is waiting (TTFB) time = 3.4 min.
Anyone know why ssrs isn't response after rending? It's a consistence problem. We have rule out network issue.

Comment: I noticed if I run it on Chrome, it's faster than IE.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like slow render related to PC hardware & browser. Chrome render a LOT faster than IE in big report. also hardware could effect speed. not sure why, only 2mb html..